# onActivityResult() not working on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to use onActivityResult to send a title, I've looked at the google implementation for the same task but it doesn't work me. Can someone help?

code for onActivityResult in mainActivity.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("There is something coming to this function" + requestCode);
        if(requestCode == NEW_TITLE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Title title = new Title(data.getStringExtra(notesSection.EXTRA_REPLY));
            mTitleViewModel.insert(title);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.empty_not_saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

code in my notesSection activity.

```
finishFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // System.out.println("Button Has Been Clicked From Notes Section");
                Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(titleEdit.getText())){
                    // System.out.println("Empty?");
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, replyIntent);
                }else{
                    // System.out.println("Sending Something Supposedly");
                    String title = titleEdit.getText().toString();
                    // System.out.println("Sending " + title);
                    replyIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_REPLY, title);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
                }
                finish();
//                startActivity(new Intent(notesSection.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
```

FYI: When I print something in the onActivityResult function, nothing shows up on my run terminal, I don't know why this is, but I don't think the function is being reached for some reason. I will send more code if necessary.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you starting your second activity from the first?

Comment: @HenryTwist Thanks for the comment but the comment below helped me solve it. I was starting it with start activity instead of startactivity for result

Comment: Yes I thought that would be the case. However I would strongly recommend taking note of the answer from @Eishon as the method you're using is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first activity try starting second activity like this

```
static int NEW_TITLE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ---

    ---

    ---

// i assume you are starting activity on some button click
// so add following line in you button on click event

startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this,notesSection.class),NEW_TITLE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

then override following method in your FIRST ACTIVITY

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == NEW_TITLE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
         // do whatever you want   
    }
}
```

Also update your finish fab on click listener

```
finishFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(titleEdit.getText())){
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, replyIntent);
            }
            else{
                replyIntent.putExtra("TITLE", titleEdit.getText().toString());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
            }
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, my problem was that I was calling the second activity with startActivity and not startActivityForResult.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this procedure has changed recently. You might want to take a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#java) so that you can implement it according to your needs.

Comment: thanks, but the comment below helped solve my problem.